# Does this one-rep answer to a one-rep question seem odd to anyone?

Tags: discussion, new-users

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/811282/how-do-you-remove-the-rdn-yahlover-worm055bccac9fec-virus-on-ubuntu-16-04) doesn't ask about a worm or malware infection outside the title, seems to be hardly a question at all.  It's from a one-rep user (still, six weeks after it was posted).  Today, it has a new "only" answer from another one-rep user, and the answer appears to be a cut-and-paste.  It looks like click bait to me, possibly linking to a dubious web site.

Or is it just me?

Comment: The question seems ok but the answer is spam. "Go to this site to fix all your computer issues" is a give away, plus the answer is focused on Windows, good catch.

Comment: The question originally caught my eye because there aren't that many worms for desktop Linux...

Comment: The question is very unclear but I think it is just badly written because the OP has asked another question too http://askubuntu.com/questions/791387/lease-on-wlan0-renews-every-15-seconds and that is right on topic, so, I think, give them the benefit of the doubt. Some new Ubuntu users are very paranoid about viruses and that is why they come to Ubuntu.

Comment: I won't argue -- that's why I came to Linux back in 2012.  I came to Kubuntu because MEPIS 11 had lost support beyond Debian security updates...

Comment: The malware proliferation in Windows Internet is annoying to no end. At least at home we can put a "no flyers" sign on our mailboxes.  Adblcoker Plus is a godsend.

Answer (score 2):

## What to flag as SPAM

Flag any answer or question that *you think* violates [this policy](https://askubuntu.com/help/promotion): if the content is flagged by other users it will be likely edited (if the SPAM is only a secondary part of the content) or deleted.

To check if a link is dangerous or SPAM, open it in the Private Browsing mode of your browser or download it with `wget` or `curl` to read the code with a **text-only** editor (local *execution* of js scripts may circumvent some protections).

## Some advices to help the users

Be very careful with the users that report a virus infection in Ubuntu, because they often download a Windows<sup>(R)</sup> malware and ClamAV reports it even if it cannot infect a Linux machine. In all cases, the reported file should be deleted, because a network may also contain Windows machines and nobody wants a virus/malware in the monthly backup.

Also, some websites try to convince the user that the system is infected and offer a download that hides a trojan horse. Some may infect **both Linux and Windows** by using social engineering (or memory exploits) to get the administrative credentials and portable languages like Python, PHP or Java to cross the barrier of executable formats. Just ask the Ubuntu user to delete any copy of the infected file, disable suspect browser extensions and never visit that web domain again.

---

I'm trying to be helpful but my answer is far from being complete and my English is weak. Feel free to ask in the comments if you have more doubts. :-)